# Flutter json response using Dio

Tags: json, flutter, dio

I have a simple response.data that get me {message: You have checked in successfully}

```
var dio = Dio();
Response response = await dio.get('http://10.0.2.2:4000/');
print(response.data); //{message: You have checked in successfully}
```

How can I just print out: You have checked in successfully? Using print(response.data.message) will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `response.data` to `Map` using the below Code,

```
 Map result = response.data;
 print(result['message']);
```